# Can we add mouse swipe effect to jquery tab

Tags: jquery-tabs, hammer.js

I want to add mouse swipe effect to jquery tab so that an user can move to another tab by swiping the mouse over the screen. I think Hammer.js could solve this problem but I have no idea about how to integrate Hammer.js with jquery-tab. I am a beginner in jquery. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```
var tabs = jQuery('.tab'),
        i = 0;

    slides
    .on('swipeleft', function(e) {
      tabs.eq(i + 1).addClass('active');
    })
    .on('swiperight', function(e) {
      tabs.eq(i - 1).addClass('active');
    });
```

Reference- http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/